# how to use genymotion with cordova?

Tags: android, apache, cordova, genymotion

i'm trying to learn cordova for app programming.
I want emulate with genymotion because in my laptop avd not work.
Now i created my first project with:

```
cordova create ciao_mondo
```

and, in "ciao_mondo" folder i add platform and i build with:

```
cordova platform add android
cordova build
```

after build successful, i run genymotion and i run app with:

```
cordova run android
```

It not work and i read follow message:

> Error: C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe: Command
>   failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037:
>   Di norma è consentito un solo utilizzo di ogni indirizzo di socket(protocollo/indirizzo di rete/porta). (10048)
>   could not read ok from ADB Server
>   * failed to start daemon *
>   error: cannot connect to daemon

can yuo help me?
Thank you

Comment: i solved! i created a cordova project from terminal and i imported it in android studio. With execution of genymotion from android studio i can run it in genyotion!

Answer (score 2):

I think I can solved this problem. The problem is about *genymotion*. Go check your gennmotion app in ADB tabs. If the link ADB default it mean you can't connect to the ADB genymotion so you should change it to your sdk folder and it work.

[image]